# react-dates DayPickerRangeController, is there a way to clean startDate or endDate if user clicks it when already selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I'm trying to find a way to let user **unselect the current selected day** if he clicks on an already selected day.
I'm using `DayPickerRangeController` from `react-dates` library.

Here is my source code:

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            startDate: null,
            endDate: null,
            focusedInput: 'startDate'
        }
    }

    handleDateChange = ({ startDate, endDate }) => {
        this.setState({ startDate, endDate });
    }

    handleFocusChange = focusedInput => {
        this.setState({ focusedInput: focusedInput || 'startDate' })
    }

    dayClick = date => {
        console.log(date)
    }


    render() {

        return (
                <DayPickerRangeController
                    onDatesChange={this.handleDateChange}
                    focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput}
                    onFocusChange={this.handleFocusChange}
                    startDate={this.state.startDate}
                    endDate={this.state.endDate}
                />
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question clearly, you have to set the `minimumNights={1}` property to not allow user pick chosen day.

```
<DayPickerRangeController
  onDatesChange={this.handleDateChange}
  focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput}
  onFocusChange={this.handleFocusChange}
  startDate={this.state.startDate}
  endDate={this.state.endDate}
  minimumNights={1}
 />
```